# Bundle Erlang OTP in COTS product

Tags: erlang, installation, rabbitmq

We want to include RabbitMQ in our product, which further requires Erlang OTP. We don't want our customers to install Erlang before they install our product and want to find out ways to include Erlang in our own product installer.

What are some strategies to do this? We want to support Windows & Linux. At the moment my understanding is that there is no ZIP version of Erlang on Windows. So here's what i am thinking

1. Include Erlang OTP installer and kick it off when our product installer runs
2. Install Erlang OTP, zip the install dir and have our product installer unzip it on the customer's machine
3. . . . ?

Thanks for any advise.

Edited on 10/21

I figured it out. When erl.exe start it spins up a name resolver daemon process (epmd.exe) for distributed erlang. The location of this exe is hard coded in /otp/install/path/bin/erl.ini.

After copying the otp installation from C:\Program Files to a directory of my choosing, I had to update the erl.ini file to reflect the change in the path to the empd process. After that I uninstalled OTP from c:\Program Files and was able to start erlang from the directory where it was copied over.

Ranjit

Comment: I think that the application wings3d is made in the way you are lookink for (it does not use OTP, but has on installation from scratch), you can look at the source here: [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wings/files/wings/1.5.1/)

Comment: I installed wings32 and saw that the installer simply extract erl.exe and bunch of compiled erlang programs. I'll install erlang otp and watch if/what registry keys it writes.

Answer (score 0):

Another option which is standard way for releases is using [rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar). This bundles OTP and it is more cleaner approach than copying the installed windows binaries and change the erl.ini or change the erl script in linux.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to respond. In my limited reading thus far, rebar seems to be a build and dependency management tool for application authored in erlang. It also presupposed an Erlang OTP installation on a machine. I am trying to figure a way to bundle Erlang OTP into a COTS product so it serves as a dependency for RabbitMQ. I'll read a little more about rebar and see if it fits the bill. I won't have any custom Erlang code as such. Essentially, when our product is installed, I want to set things up so that RabbitMQ is able to resolve a path to erl on Windows and Linux.